# python (matplotlib) __NSAutoreleaseNoPool error ... - just leaking

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

[I originally posted this in serverfault, but was advised there to post it here instead.]

Matplotlib is a python library for data visualization.  When I attempt to display a graph on the screen, I get the following error/warnings:

```
2012-12-21 16:40:05.532 python[9705:903] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x103e25d80 of class NSCFArray autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2012-12-21 16:40:05.534 python[9705:903] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x103e26820 of class __NSFastEnumerationEnumerator autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2012-12-21 16:40:05.535 python[9705:903] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x103e9f080 of class NSObject autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
```

FWIW, one way to produce these results is shown below; all the steps shown (including the call to ipython) are taken from a matplotlib tutorial:

```
% ipython
...
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [2]: plt.plot([1, 3, 2, 4])
Out[3]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x106aabd90>]

In [3]: plt.show()
```

ALso, FWIW, I've observed *exactly the same behavior* with multiple styles of installation (on the same machine) of python+numpy+matplotlib+ipython, including installs that use the system-supplied python, those that use the python installed by `homebrew`, or those that use a python installed directly from source into a location off my home directory.

Any ideas of what may be going on, or what I could do about it?

Comment: Looks like a bug in matplotlib

Comment: try starting ipython with `ipython -pylab` which will auto-import pyplot, numpy, and a bunch of other useful packages.  Also try playing with adding threading options when starting `ipython` http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/reference.html#eventloop-integration

Comment: Can you also add which version of osx you are using?

Comment: one other possible solution, have you tried using the enthought (https://www.enthought.com/) packaging?  I know several people who report that it is basically a turn-key solution to getting everything useful running an macs (I would also suggest removing _everything_ else you tried first unless you understand the path really well).

Answer (score 4):

I am having the same problem, one solution I found is to add the line:

```
plt.ion()
```

before the first plotting command.  This turns on the interactive plotting mode and the error messages go away.  This has only worked for me when plotting on the command line, if I do ion() and then show() in a script the plots don't show up at all, and if I leave the ion() out, I can see my plots, but I get the error messages.  This has only happened since updated to version 1.2.0.

Answer (score 1):

It's trying to do something with Cocoa, but Cocoa hasn't really been initialized or anything. You may be able to silence the errors and fix the problems by running this before:

```
from Foundation import NSAutoreleasePool
pool = NSAutoreleasePool()
```

And this after:

```
from AppKit import NSApplication
NSApplication.sharedApplication().run()
```

This requires PyObjC. Unfortunately, this may only allow for displaying one plot per IPython session. You may wish to try the IPython notebook instead, which removes the dependency on Cocoa.