# Error when plotting with matplotlib.pyplot.plot()

Tags: python, matplotlib, macports

The following code gives errors I don't understand why :

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    a = np.arange(10)
    plt.plot(a)
    [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x116be8890>]
    plt.show()

    2013-01-29 10:58:18.891 Python[27257:903] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x105b27810 of class NSCFArray autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
    2013-01-29 10:58:18.893 Python[27257:903] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x105b37f60 of class __NSFastEnumerationEnumerator autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
    2013-01-29 10:58:18.895 Python[27257:903] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x105bee900 of class NSObject autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
```

I have matplotlib 1.2.0, numpy 1.6.2, python 2.7.3 and ipython 0.13.1. The packages have been installed with macports. This is doing it on Mac OS 10.6.8, and I don't see it on 10.7.5.

Edit : [this post shows the same error, although no solution has been clearly found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004243/python-matplotlib-nsautoreleasenopool-error-just-leaking)

Comment: [This link](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.pygame/4128) may help you out if you haven't seen it.

Comment: Thanks. I had seen it before and checked whether I had pyobjc installed or not. It turns out I have PyObjC 2.4 and PyObjC-cocoa 2.4 installed with macports too.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a solution yet. My workaround has been to install another backend : qt4. This requires to do :

```
    sudo port install qt4-mac
    sudo port install py27-qt4
```

and then modify (or create if None) the file ~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc by adding :

```
    backend : QT4Agg
```

Then the above text works without problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having this problem, my work around is to add:

```
plt.ion()
```

before the first plot command.  This turns on the interactive plotting mode and it makes the errors go away.